hose bib access through wall too low
For whatever reason my house was constructed with a hose bib wall hole that is only about 2 inches off the ground. Trying to figure out what's a good way to install a hose bib. I'd like to avoid having to drill a new hole and cover the old one for aesthetic reasons. Here are my ideas:

Just install a hose bib that's 2 inches off the ground, but turn it 90 degrees so you can attach a hose on the side and turn the valve on side.

Attach a 90 degree fitting, go up another foot along wall, another 90 degree sticking out with a nipple pipe to attach hose bib. I'm a little concerned about what pipe material to use since this will be over a foot of piping and fixtures exposed to the elements. I know copper and freeze temps are no good, and PVC and PEX don't like UV rays.


Any suggestions?

If you have reasonable access inside the house, you can install a shutoff inside for the winter.

I would go with #1 if allowed.  Water and/or hose will not care.  It also follows the KISS principle for using the least amount of fittings to do the job.

@DrMoishePippik   Remind me not to move to Mass.

@DrMoishePippik: Broken link

@DrMoishePippik not sure what you mean by "no plumber-approved repairs."  If all work must be done by a licensed plumber, doesn't that mean all plumbers' repairs are approved?  Do you mean "no homeowner-approved repairs?"

@Huesmann, The wording is unclear, and will be changed.

It depends on your locale. For example, in the U.S. state Massachusetts,  homeowner-performed repairs cannot later be certified by a plumber -- all such work must be done by a licensed plumber. "Massachusetts law prohibits anyone but a licensed professional from installing, removing or repairing plumbing."  https://www.mass.gov/info-details/plumbers-and-gas-fitters-consumer-fact-sheet
